# C++: bool method returning unexpected numbers after cout statement

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on some exam-examples for a c++ programming exam and the example where I'm stuck at requires me to code a class for returning the contents of a "Closet" object. One of the methods required in the example adds a vector of Garment objects to a second vector of Garment objects, (so, filling the closet with clothes). Up until this point my code has passed all the references and checks I've been given (a list with the supposed runtime errors and cout/cerr statements), so I've removed method-definitions and calls in the code I'm posting here to only show the part where I'm getting the unexpected returns.

I supposed that one of the constructors or even another method might interfere with the output, so I've ran several versions of the code trough a visualizer (Python tutor for c++), but that didn't shed any new insight either, no other methods were called (as expected) and no other output prompted from the constructors either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


enum class Color{Red, Blue, Gray, Yellow};
const std::vector<std::string> color_names{"red", "blue", "gray", "yellow"};

enum class Type{Pants, Blouse, Shirt, Skirt};
const std::vector<std::string> type_names{"pants", "blouse", "shirt", "skirt"};

class Garment {
  int preis;
  Color farbe;
  Type typ;


  public:

  //Konstruktor
  Garment (int p, Color f = Color::Gray, Type t = Type::Pants){

      this->preis = p;
      this->farbe = f;
      this->typ = t;

      //negativer Preis = exception

      if (p < 0){throw runtime_error("Preis kleiner als 0!");} }



int get_price() const{
return this->preis; }

    Type get_type() const{
    return this->typ; }

    bool has_color(Color f) const{}

    void deteriorate(int w){}

    int get_index_color() const{}

int get_index_type() const{}    



   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Garment &g){
        //[40000 Cent, yellow blouse]

out << "[" << g.preis << " Cent, "<< color_names[g.get_index_color()] 
<< " " << type_names[g.get_index_type()];
        out << "]";
        return out;

    } 


};

class Closet {
size_t capacity;
vector<Garment> inventory;


public:
//Konstruktor Beginn

Closet (size_t c, vector<Garment> inv){

    this->capacity = c;
    this->inventory = inv;

if (capacity < 5 || capacity > 300){throw runtime_error ("Komplette Kapazitaet ueber oder unterschritten!");}


if (this->inventory.size() > this->capacity){throw runtime_error ("Relative kapazitaet ueberschritten");}


        vector<int>kleiderliste {0,0,0,0};

         for (auto x : inv){
              if (x.Garment::get_type() == Type::Pants){kleiderliste[0]++;}
              if (x.Garment::get_type() == Type::Blouse){kleiderliste[1]++;}
              if (x.Garment::get_type() == Type::Skirt){kleiderliste[2]++;}
             if (x.Garment::get_type() == Type::Shirt){kleiderliste[3]++;}
         }

       int zaehler = 0;
        for (auto y : kleiderliste){
              if (y != 0 ){zaehler++;}
         }
    if (zaehler <2){throw runtime_error("Nur mehr kleidungsstuecke eines typs im schrank");}



}


bool add(vector<Garment> v){

            if ((v.size() + this->inventory.size()) <= this->capacity){
            cerr << 1;
            this->inventory.insert(this->inventory.begin(),v.begin(),v.end());
            return true;
            }else{
            cerr << 0;
            return false;
            }

}

double mean_price() const{

}

friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out,const Closet &c){

    out << "[" << c.capacity << ",{";
     for (auto x : c.inventory){
        out <<x;
     }

    out << "},";
    out << c.mean_price();
    out << "]";

    return out;

    }
};

int main(){

Garment pants{34500, Color::Blue, Type::Pants};
Garment blouse{12700, Color::Red, Type::Blouse};
const Garment shirt{2300, Color::Yellow, Type::Shirt};
Garment shirt2{23500, Color::Red, Type::Shirt};
Garment skirt{26600, Color::Gray, Type::Skirt};
Garment skirt2{4600, Color::Blue, Type::Skirt};


Closet closet {10, {skirt, blouse, shirt, pants, skirt}}; 
cout << closet.add({shirt2, skirt2}) << closet.add({blouse,skirt,pants}) << closet.add({}) << closet.add({pants}) << '\n';

 return 0; }
```

This code is supposed to yield the following output via cout:
1110. The Closet::add method is supposed to return true three times and false one time in a row.

What I actually get as return values via cout << is: 0111
To test if the code does what it's supposed to I'm outputting 1 for true and 0 for false on the cerr channel too, and there I get the correct 1110 numbers.

What leads to the return output not be 1110? Are the method calls made in a different order in the compiler?

Comment: The order of evaluation for `<<` is not guaranteed to be left to right. The compiler is allowed to evaluate the parameters in any order. So it could decide to do `closet.add({})` first, and save the result. Then `closet.add({pants})` and save the result. Etc. After calling all the functions, it can then print all the saved results. Your code is sensitive to order of evaluation, which helps explain the odd behavior. In your `add` function, print the price of the thing being added, and you'll see that they are being added out of order.

Comment: @RaymondChen: actually C++17 introduced enforcing of order of evaluation for some operators, including `operator<<`, please refer to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf

Comment: In the future when constructing a [mcve] you should delete the code that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem. Shorter code is easier to read, and in this particular case deleting the unnecessary code removes several compile warnings.

Comment: Thank you three for the comments and explanation - our course still enforces using a c++ 11 compiler, and I've tried three different ones now, with coming to 2 different results (one of them being the expected one), so the issue is indeed there. That might lead to further trouble down the road for me, but it clears this question up - thank you! And I'll take the suggestions for further code-examples to heart!

Comment: The best thing to do is to not have side effects in the things being passed to `<<`, then you won't have the problem. Either that, or use several different statements separated by a `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Raymond-Chen the method is not guaranteed to be called in the left to right order that would produce the expected "1110" output. Different compilers lead to different order of the calls being executed. In this specific case switching to the clang compiler yielded the expected "1110" output.